# want to downgrade my operating system on galaxy s3 GT-19300

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-3, downgrade

i have updated my galaxy s3 GT-19300 to android kitkat 4.4.2 
now i want my earlier version back on my mobile 
so what is the procedure for that

Answer (score 2):

From your question its clear that your phone is rooted. So if you want to go back to CM 10.2 from CM 11 , you need to **download stable build from [Cyanogen Portal](http://download.cyanogenmod.org)** for your device and **flash it using ClockWorkMod recovery or any other compatible recovery**. Similar to how you done with CM 11. You can backup App Data. But its recommending a clean install.